# The supremum of a set of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a set of sets of natural numbers:

$$ S=\big\{ S_n=\{10n+1,10n+2\}\,\big|\,n\in\mathbb{N}  \big\} ~~.$$

The $S_n$ sets are $\{11,12\}$, $\{21,22\}$, $\{31,32\}$, etc.  If I take the union

$$S'=\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^m S_k $$

can I say that $S_m$ is the supremum of $S'$?  My meaning would be that since $S'$ is a set of sets, its supremum should also be a set.  However, there is ambiguity because in some sense one might say that $10m+2$ is the supremum of $S'$.  What is the standard language for such distinctions?  Equally, I might have defined $S$ as a set of intervals, in which case I think the language should be the same:

$$ S=\big\{ S_n=[10n+1,10n+2]\,\big|\,n\in\mathbb{N}  \big\}  ~~.$$

Comment: Don't you need a linear ordering in order to say "supremum"?

Comment: @Randall is right. The definition of the supremum needs an ordered set to begin with.

Comment: What word means, "The $S_k$ with the greatest element in it is $S_m$?"